# Why doesn't explicit bool() conversion happen in contextual conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

If the following test-programm

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A() {}
    explicit operator bool() const {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
//    explicit operator bool() {
//        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
//        return true;
//    }
    const operator int() const {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    operator int() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    if (a) {
        std::cout << "bool()" << std::endl;
    }
    if (a + 0) {
        std::cout << "int()" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

is run, the output is

```
int A::operator int()
bool()
int A::operator int()
int()
```

and not

```
bool A::operator _Bool()
bool()
int A::operator int()
int()
```

what I expected (and what you get if you uncomment the commented parts).

So the question is what are the rules giving the conversion to non-const-int precedence over converting to const-bool?

Comment: which compiler? `const operator int() const` should fail the compilation

Comment: compiler is clang-3.4

Comment: Can you update the question title to remove the double-negative. I would do it myself, but I'm not sure whether to remove the "doesn't" or the "not". Or even both?

Comment: ok, just clearified the title. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When performing overload resolution on a reference binding, the less cv-qualified type is preferred.  This is discussed in 13.3.3.2p3, with the example given:

```
struct X {
  void f() const;
  void f();
};
void g(const X& a, X b) {
  a.f(); // calls X::f() const
  b.f(); // calls X::f()
}
```

Note that binding an object to the implicit object parameter of a member function (13.3.1.1.1p2) is a reference binding (13.3.3.1.4).

Conversion operators are treated as member functions (13.3.1.5) for the purposes of overload resolution (13.3p2).  Contextual conversion to `bool` has the semantics of initialization (4p4).

Importantly, any conversion required on the return type of the conversion operator is considered only *after* considering overload resolution between the conversion operators themselves (13.3.3p1).

The solution is to ensure that all conversion operators have the same `const`-qualification, especially to scalar type.

Comment: *"Importantly, any conversion required on the return type of the conversion operator is considered only after considering overload resolution between the conversion operators themselves (13.3.3p1)."* Hmm there's the bullet that starts with *"the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion"* which seems to imply this was fully intended. +1

Comment: @dyp there isn't a UDCS here, because we're not resolving between different functions with an `X` argument.  There would be UDCSs if we had `f(bool); f(float); X x; f(x);` and indeed those UDCSs are ambiguous.

Comment: The whole conversion from `A` to `bool` is a UDCS (in the OP's example), but nevertheless the overload resolution is applied "too early" IMHO, where the UDC required to convert from `A` to `bool` isn't considered, but only used to define the viable functions (so only the SCS for the implied object argument is considered for overload resolution).

Comment: Hmm your example might be the *reason* why overload resolution of the conversion function happens so early: If the context is the call to an overloaded function (and not like in the OP, a conversion with a fixed target type), there are two overload resolution steps to perform: 1. selecting a conversion function 2. selecting an overload of `f`.

Answer (score 4):

> what are the rules giving the conversion to non-const-int precedence over converting to const-bool?

Using const member function of a non-const object, requires conversion of a non-const object into const-object. That is why `operator int()` has a better match over `operator bool() const`.

To make it a bit clearer, if you would remove int operators, what really happens with the first bool context (first if) is this :

```
if ( const_cast<const A&>(a).operator bool() ) {
```

Instead, what happens is this :

```
if ( a.operator int() )
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really work out since the commented operator in the OPs question is also explicit and changes the behaviour just because of `const`. Also, the explicit `operator bool` can be used without casting in a boolean context (such as `if`). This is a very easy way to implement the safe bool idiom in C++11.

Comment: So to use the expilicit-bool-idiom in c++11 correctly one has to implement both the const and non-const version of operator bool(). Just to prevent other conversion operators to kick in?

Comment: I don't quite understand how the ranking happens for this overload resolution. Typically, binding some `A` to an `A const&` is direct reference binding, and therefore considered an Exact Match. Therefore, the implied object argument should match exactly the implicit object parameter in both cases. Then, there's a UDC for both, but for the conversion to `int`, a Boolean Conversion follows. Clearly, that's not what's happening in the compilers, the matching of the implied object argument is somehow ranked differently..

Comment: @wimalopaan Either that, or implement only const version of conversion operators.

Comment: @dyp I am trying to figure out which paragraph in the standard is important. I think it is [conv.quel], but it talks about pointers - not references. It still has to convert from lvalue into prvalue to call the `operator bool() const`, making `operator int()` more qualified.

Comment: The rank of a conversion sequence required to bind to a reference is described in [over.ics.ref]. Pointers are different from references for overload resolution! If we just considered some functions `void foo(A&); void foo(A const&);`, then [over.ics.rank] would disambiguate between those two. However, I think in the OP's example, we have ONE conversion sequence: a UDC, which *contains* a standard conversion sequence. It seems as if the part in [over.ics.rank] about reference bindings as Standard Conversion Sequences still applies, which I don't understand, as we have a UDC here.

Comment: @wimalopaan: "So to use the explicit-bool-idiom in c++11 correctly one has to implement both the const and non-const version of operator bool(), just to prevent other conversion operators to kick in?" @BЈовић: "Either that, or implement only const version of conversion operators." I'd have said, "Either that, or implement no other [implicit] conversion operators." `explicit operator bool() const` has no need to outcompete an `operator int()` if you do not write any `operator int()` for your type!